# Putting marker and save location in DB for Leaflet.draw?

Tags: leaflet-draw

[image: Map on which I am working]

Using Leaflet.draw, I managed to set a marker, but I need to save it to a database, so that when reloading the page again, it shows the marker that was saved.

I'm not an English speaker, but I try.

Comment: Andy como solucionaste tienes algun repo de git?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/98116)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add event for [draw:created](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw). In this event, get the added layer, its type and read the geometry according to the layer type, type is marker in your case. Here is the basic code:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
            layer = e.layer;
            var lat = layer.getLatLng().lat;
            var lng = layer.getLatLng().lng;

            if (e.layerType === 'marker') {
                //layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
            }
        });
```

Then save marker's lat/lng to the database.

Comment: Thanks Bro!! But I have other problem, how can I passed HTML var to PHP, I mean, var lat and var lng, how I do to put in php code?

Comment: You can use jquery ajax to call PHP script and send lat/lng as parameters, here is some help regarding that: http://thisinterestsme.com/simple-ajax-request-example-jquery-php/